# How to set the exact distance between the edge of a paper and text

Tags: margins

I need 3 cm of space between edge of a paper and text on four sides. I tried to set margin value to 3 cm, but it did not work. Also, I tried to set other parameters as `\marginparsep` to `0pt`, but it did not work either.

This is how I tried (in ShareLatex):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe=true}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt} 
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How precisely did you try?

Comment: \usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}

\geometry{showframe=true}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt} 
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt} 
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}

Comment: @egreg Still haven't got a single 3 cm border(:

Comment: Please, edit your question, rather than adding code in comments

Comment: What's the problem with `margin=3cm`? Are you printing the page and measuring the distance? If so, *don't* print using a "fit to page" setting. Are you interested in a 3cm margin to the *text block*?

Comment: Yes, I'm measuring and even without "fit to page" borders are not 3 cm. Yes, I'm interested in a 3cm margin to the text block.

Comment: what document class are you using?  (some document classes don't interact well with the geometry package.)

Comment: You need to help us understand the meaning of "did not work".  Do you mean on screen or on paper?.  One thing I have found (on PC's) is that when printing PDF documents, make sure you print them "actual size" rather than "shrink to fit".  The latter option will take a well-margined document and screw it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way in which LaTeX sets up pages is quite complicated (see section 3 of the [geometry package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for more details). Changing margin settings etc. directly is therefore inadvisable, unless you are sure you know what you are doing. Instead, I suggest the following. Set the text width to the paper width minus 60mm, and set the text height to the paper height minus 60mm (for a4, this is 150mm x 237mm). The geometry package will horizontally centre your text, but it will leave extra room for the footer, so set `top` (which is everything above the text) to 30mm. Make sure you tell your printer not to scale the pages if you are going to print and measure the results.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=150mm,top=30mm,textheight=237mm]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe=true}
\begin{document}
ABCDEF
\end{document}
```